# Filter syntax error

Tags: web-services, wcf, odata

Can't find what is wrong with filter syntax:

```
http://localhost:27161/NorthwindsService.svc/Categories?$select=CategoryName,CategoryID&$filter=CategoryName Eq 'Beverages'
```

Have error:

```
Syntax error at position 15 in 'CategoryName Eq 'Beverages''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OData queries are case sensitive. Eq is not a valid operator for the filter query, but eq is.

this should work :

```
http://localhost:27161/NorthwindsService.svc/Categories?$select=CategoryName,CategoryID&$filter=CategoryName eq 'Beverages'
```

Comment: Strange that book `MCSD Certification Toolkit (Exam 70-483): Programming in C# ` shows `Eq` but not `eq`

Comment: I checked the book and there is indeed an error in the table 9-14, all $filter options are capitalized which is wrong. But a few pages before there's an exemple of a $filter query with the eq operator in lower case. I imagine this might be a case of a word processor autocapitalizing the first word of a sentence.